# Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications :

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to do a Maven realeas prepare but this error keeps happening
I tried to execlude the root pom from being checked but it goes now to the other poms

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project sfg-pet-clinic: Cannot prepare the release because you h
ave local modifications : 

[ERROR] [pet-clinic-data/pom.xml:modified]

[ERROR] [pet-clinic-web/pom.xml:modified]
```

and this is an example of my root pom :

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>install</goals>
                    <checkModificationExcludes>
                        <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                    </checkModificationExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/OmarSharif93/sfg-pet-clinic.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

what can I do to resolve this ?

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   pet-clinic-data/pom.xml
        deleted:    pet-clinic-data/pom.xml.releaseBackup
        modified:   pet-clinic-web/pom.xml
        deleted:    pet-clinic-web/pom.xml.releaseBackup
        modified:   pom.xml
        deleted:    pom.xml.releaseBackup

Comment: So you should exclude the `.releaseBackup` files from git with .gitignore, but you need to commit your pom.xml changes before you run `mvn release:prepare`.

Comment: I did the changes but it ran into a new error 
Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'

Comment: Was there some more output than just that?

Comment: this is what the error look like 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:pr
epare (default-cli) on project sfg-pet-clinic: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'

Comment: Odd that there was no other output. try `mvn -X release:prepare` and put the output in your question.

Comment: If you have a new error, please ask a new question.

Comment: so I post the output in a new Question?

Comment: Yes, a different error means a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Committed the `pom.xml` and it solved the problem.